# C++ and Thrift: Reference needed to get started

Tags: c++, linux, thrift

I have read about Thrift while trying to find out how to use Google Protocol Buffers. I have been searching for some reference that shows how to go about using it with a simple working example for C++. It's been frustrating not being able to find any such site. It is a bit surprising that almost all the examples use Java, a language that has cross-platform RMI already at its disposal. May be I have missed something in searching, and I would very much appreciate if anyone can give a reference to a tutorial with a working example, however small.
TIA,
-Sviya

Comment: Never had to wait this long on stackoverflow. I guess Thrift has unlimited stack ;)

Answer (score 2):

I've never used Thrift, but Googling for "thrift" brought me to this page -  http://incubator.apache.org/thrift/ - which has a C++ example at the bottom of the page.

The thrift wiki has this page - http://wiki.apache.org/thrift/ThriftUsageC%2B%2B - which has more info on using it with C++

Answer (score 0):

Also,
once when you install thrift in folder tutorial you have example of thrift file,
server&client implementations in different languages and README file.

This is good place to start!

Answer (score 0):

Because there were no tutorial on the web, I created one in my blog.
You can check my full tutorial about Thrift in: [My Blog](http://anoori.me/blog/programming/thriftpart-one-introduction/)

Since it's too long, I cannot post my answer here. But I think my blog is a good resource for anyone who wants to get started with Thrift.

Comment: Your links are no longer working. They take me to the front page of your site. Also, when I dig into your blog, the links don't work, either. Specifically, I was trying to click through to the C# tutorial piece.

Comment: @ingyhere Sorry. I updated the link here. Please check it now. I'll update the other links in a bit. Thanks for reporting.

Comment: This blog does not exist.

Comment: @ArnoldSpence Sorry, I've changed my domain. I tried to change all the links on the web but this one slipped.

Comment: BTW, the formatting of the blog is a bit messed up. I'll try to fix it ASAP but it's the result of the migration. Some posts just didn't convert correctly.